# Pass data from block to view

Tags: magento, view, block

I found that you can set data to the view from block by setting it to your xml file. Is there's a way to set it without accessing your xml file? And another question, how can I pass data from controller to block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For passing data from block to view**

In block use

```
$this->setVariableName($value) or $this->assign(‘variableName’, $value)
```

In template use

```
$this->getVariableName() or $variableName respectively
```

**For passing data from controller to block**

It's not the responsibility of the controller to set variables for the view.

Controller set values from Models and block retrieves values from that model.

You can do this by:

- Creating a model class that inherits from `Varien_object`
- In the controller, instantiate that object using this code:

  ```
  $object = Mage::getSingleton('model')
  $object->setVar($value) or  $object->setData('var', $value)
  ```
- Later access the variable by

  ```
  $var = $object->getVar()
  ```

Hope you got what was needed :)

Comment: Using `->assign('variable', $value)` how can I catch the data inside `My_Block.php`?

Comment: Didn't get you..
Where exactly you want to assign the variable
From above I have assigned in a controller and got the value in block

Comment: My bad, bad context. I was trying to catch the assigned data into an observer using block instance. To be more specific, i was trying to catch the $tabs variable assigned to tabs widget inside an observer.