# Get Product ID throught url in Custom page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, module

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

i created one custom module in my magento,Its working great.

Using this i created that one http://www.phparrow.com/magento/magento-create-a-simple-module/

in my product page i have a link

`<a href = "http://www.example.com/magenaresh/index.php/hello/ "> Click Here </a>`

when i click **Click Here** its redirecting to **http://www.example.com/magenaresh/index.php/hello/** this URL upto here every thing is ok...

But now i want to pass the ProductID along with URL

for this i wrote like this

```
<?php 
    $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    echo $product_id;
?>
```

AND

```
<a href = "http://www.example.com/magenaresh/index.php/hello/<?php echo $product_id ?> ">Click Here</a>
```

again i clicked on `Click Here` its showing

[image]

Any thing wrong i did here ?

Any Ideas ?

Comment: who did that? delete ur comment is better

Comment: I'm guessing config.xml needs to know about the extra parameter?

Comment: Check This 

This Link might be help full >>   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469767/get-url-query-string

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request using a third party software, here namely Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add link at you href like

```
<a href = "http://www.example.com/magenaresh/index.php/hello/index/index/product_id/<?php echo $product_id ?> ">Click Here</a>
```

And in your  controller can access the URL parameters in the exact same way as before;

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->get('product_id');
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Yeah..Thanks :) its working for me & how can i explode the product id here

Comment: you can get like $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product_id'); let me know is it useful

Comment: No its not working.. I wants to get the product id in hello.phtml

Comment: will u please vote up my answer so some one can trust and use in future. Use get and set methods to get your product value refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270655/pass-data-from-block-to-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006183/magento-passing-data-between-a-controller-and-a-block

Answer (score 1):

Hello check below code

```
<a href = "http://www.example.com/magenaresh/index.php/hello/index/index/<?php echo $product_id ?> ">Click Here</a>
```